# What happens if you enter an alliance with the Papacy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, I have the delightful pleasure to marry off my non-heir son. One of the options is a courtier in the Papacy with less-than-admirable attributes. Still, it sound like a fun thing to do. Has anyone tried this? Is it any different from any other alliance?

I imagine that the Pope would attempt to bugger me into joining any of his little disputes ... and that he'll likely not give much help in return.

(Plot twist! It's actually the legitimized bastard daughter of the Pope himself and some lowborn promiscuous lady.)

Comment: Is marriage to a courtier actually marked as giving you an alliance in this case? Normally, you cannot get an alliance by marrying a mere courtier. As far as I am aware, you can't even normally get an alliance with the papacy because of this.

Comment: I haven't seen it before either, but it must be because she is his daughter. Marrying a relative of the pope gives you 0 prestige, as it happens.

Comment: Yeah that would explain it. My expectation is that he probably wont involve you in very many wars until the Muslims start to approach rome. Normally catholics won't attack the pope and vice versa

Comment: Does AI raise mercenaries when called into war? If so, having the pope as an ally could be a boon, as he is very very rich. However, if he is very old the alliance might not last too long so use it quickly. Also, calling people to wars pisses them off, which could get you excommunicated if the said person is the pope.

Comment: @SMeznaric That's an interesting thought. I will make some experiments next weekend and report back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, essentially nothing. You may or may not be able to call him into wars, and he may or may not do the same.

Interesting thing happens though if you're an emperor-tier ruler and have an anti-pope installed. You gain a CB to install your anti-pope, and if successful can vassalize the pope (assuming you have a de jure claim or the anti-pope is of your dynasty, as usual).

Comment: What does a de-jure claim on the Papacy entail? Owning the Kingdom of Italy title?